# Trigger.io bluetooth permission?

Tags: android, bluetooth, trigger.io

I am working with a bluetooth hardware device and I am trying to get it to interface with my Trigger.IO application.  It seems as though it is not possible, even though technically it should.  Here are my steps so far:

- Used the Trigger.IO module functionality to create a module which was able to successfully send and receive messages between the Trigger.IO app and native Java code
- Created a native Android application which successfully communicated with the bluetooth hardware device
- Ported my native Android bluetooth code over into my Trigger.IO module

At this point the custom module is included in the Trigger app and seems to starting correctly, but when I make a call that should initiate the bluetooth device connection logic I am getting errors about bluetooth permissions.  I ensured that my module has the necessary bluetooth permissions within its `AndroidManifest.xml`, but my fear is that the base Trigger app does not have the required permissions.

These are logs that output within the LogCat when the attempting to start the bluetooth connection:

```
D/Forge: Native call module.startDevicePolling with task.params: {}
D/BluetoothManagerService: Message: 20
D/BluetoothManagerService: Added callback: Android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManagerCallback$Stub$Proxy@41f84218:true
W/dalvikvm: threadid=25: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41612ba8)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11967 SIG: 9
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Incoming Data Thread
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: io.trigger.forge42a1430afae511e2a0e61231392b77b0, PID: 11967
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10230 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
```

Looking at the `AndroidManfiest.xml` at the root of the deployed .APK it looks as though Trigger only has permissions for INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.  Anyone else run into this?  I think if I can get the BLUETOOTH permission into the root `AndroidManifest.xml` that things will work, but that file is encoded to not make that easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger.io does support the ability for module's to add permissions - see [Changing build configuration](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native%5fmodules/native%5fbuild%5fsteps.html)

In summary:

1. Add a build steps file in `android/build_steps.json`
2. For your scenario, update the build steps file with: `[ { "do": { "android_add_permission": { "permission": "android.permission.BLUETOOTH" } } } ]`
3. After changing the build steps for either Android or iOS it is important to update the inspector project

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by changing the local trigger android template to give me the permission I needed.  This is obviously not ideal.  It would be ideal to have the Trigger logic look at the native modules, derive the required permissions, and update their master `AndroidManifest.xml` accordingly.

Comment: You could also use a [Trigger.io postbuild hook](https://trigger.io/docs/current/tools/hooks.html) to change the content of the AndroidManifest.xml automatically after each `forge run`. Might be less hacky.